# PHP - str_replace not working as expected

Tags: php, drupal-6, str-replace

I have a variable called path that is a url e.g.

```
www.google.co.uk%3Fq%3Dde
```

which i am running through 2 str_replace to format properly.

```
  $path = str_replace('%3F', '?', $path); 
  $path = str_replace ('%3D', '=', $path);
```

I am then printing the output but the "**%3F**" and "**%3D**" are still being printed. This did previously work when i used these 2 str_replace

```
  $path = str_replace('%3F', '?'); 
  $path = str_replace ('%3D', '=');
```

But drupal 6 throws up errors when i use these.

I am quite new to php so it may be something simple that i am missing

Comment: The function str_replace needs at least 3 arguments. So str_replace('%3F', '?'); can't be working, but i don't know, why the other str_replace's aren't working.

Comment: This works for me, what errors are you seeing?

Comment: Your example is incomplete/wrong, unable to reproduce, see: http://codepad.org/AubDoGw4 - double check what `$path` contains *really*. - Also if you ask a question because you get errors, please specify the errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `str_replace()` for this. Use [`urldecode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.urldecode.php) instead, as this is its designed purpose.

```
echo urldecode("www.google.co.uk%3Fq%3Dde");
// www.google.co.uk?q=de
```

Without seeing the rest of your code, it is difficult to say why your first two `str_replace()` calls failed. They are correctly formed.

Comment: Thanks for that Michael, unfortunately it isnt working still, but i think it is beyond the scope of this question. You have definitely shown the flaw in my logic with using str_replace!

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$path = urldecode($url);
```

(http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Should be: **You are missing $path in str_replace for last two lines:**

```
$path = "www.google.co.uk%3Fq%3Dde";
$path = str_replace('%3F', '?', $path); 
$path = str_replace ('%3D', '=', $path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's urldecode function.

```
    $url = "www.google.co.uk%3Fq%3Dde";
    $path = urldecode($url);
```